# Simple DOM Google Plus

Tags: simple-html-dom

I'm using Simple HTML Dom to parse various websites. All is working fine except when I try to parse through a google plus page. I attempted the below to troubleshoot and even this isn't working. When I echo out another page it works fine but something like the below only shows a blank page. I thought I'd have to be logged in to google plus but even after that it's still just a blank page. Any ideas on why I can't load this page? Is it something google forbids and locks? The interesting thing is the page title loads up by the favicon but nothing elsel. Here's an example of the code I have. Thanks for your help!

```
$url_link = "https://plus.google.com/+pollotropical/about";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url_link);
echo $html;
```